# .htaccess mod_rewrite check if querystring var is avail

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I want to rewrite my urls so that it is `website.com/folder/` sometimes though I need it to rewrite also `website.com/folder/page/`

Currently I have it working with just the `website.com/folder/` but can not get it to check if there is a page, if I create just another rule under the folder one it reads that one, and gives me an empty page var, which is breaking my php. I struggle with .htaccess and any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have that works with just the folder but I can not include a page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|images|html|docs)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?folder=$1 [QSA]
```

Here is what I tried to get it to work with either just a folder, or a folder and page

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|images|html|doc)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?folder=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|images|html|doc)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?folder=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Please Help!

Comment: Hard to understand as it is. Try showing the complete incoming URI to see where and how is the query that you are trying to back reference in you rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [the RewriteRule docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) you should reverse the rules order in your rules set. Because in your configuration both rules have the same `RewriteCond`, the most specific rule (folder + page) should be atop and the most general rule should be the last one. If not when the first rule is matched the URL is rewritten and the second rule never matches. Also, probably you want to remove the trailing forward slash in the pattern of your folder + page rule (assuming that the second group in the pattern matches a page not a folder). So I think the whole thing should read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|images|html|doc)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?folder=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(css|js|images|html|doc)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?folder=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: @user1911854 I've updated my answer. I hope it will be useful to you now.